# Json update without changing structure using java

Tags: json

Hi                                This is regarding json read and update without knowing format. My requirement is read json and update any field including array.if i want to update empid and any array field say for example role specific field finally structure should not change could you please help on this and I stuck in this concept. I saw some references that is not helping like creating pojo class or using get method from json object. This is completely new to me please assist                                         Format                                { “Empid” : “1235”                                  “  name”: “steve”}                     “Emparray”[{ “role”: “ASP”                    “Date”: “220122”            },{“role”: “JSP”                               “Date”: “230122”}]}

Comment: What language are you doing this in and how have you tried to solve this? Can you show your attempt so far?

Comment: Post a *valid* JSON example, tag the language you want to use, and show your coding attempt.

Comment: Language isJava